# I'm trying to replicate redirected folders with a WORKGROUP setup (Windows 10 Pro)

Tags: windows-10, networking, windows-domain, workgroup

I have 10 workstations, all services are managed through head office and are cloud services.  Therefore, I would like to setup my office with a WORKGROUP setup, instead of a DOMAIN.

I have put a NAS drive on the network.

I started with one workstation and I have gone to %USERPROFILE% > Desktop > Properties > Location and changed the location of the DESKTOP to the NAS drive (z:\Users\myuser\Desktop).

Everything copied over to the new location as expected and the location of the files is correctly in Z:\Users\myuser\Desktop.

However, when I close (or minimize) all windows and right-click on the DESKTOP, all that happens is a circle twirling, then the page goes black for a second and the page reloads.  All the same windows are still open, all the icons are there, but nothing else happens.  No context menu shows, I don't have the option to select Personalize or Display Settings (or anything).

Does anyone know why this is happenening?

Can I not use a NAS for the user folders (Desktop, Documents, Pictures, Music & Videos)?

Comment: I've just recreated your setup. I've used both mapped network drive and UNC path, everything works fine(I was using a simple windows share as target folder). Does that problem occur on all worstations or only one?

Comment: Actually, I rebooted and it seems to have fixed the problem.  However, I'm going to look into using Sync Center & offline files because when the NAS was off the desktop was not available and then it messed up all my pinned apps (to the taskbar).

Comment: That too, works fine, I've tested that on the first run. Sync Center and Offline files were activated automaticaly on Windows v1909, Your OS just had a hickup(probably). Acctualy I was quite suprised how everything was working great, I've never try this outside of Domain environment. Gl.!

Comment: The problem is back and every time I right-click on the desktop it keeps spinning and then reloads the desktop icons again.